# Why is completion not working?

Tags: org-mode, completion

I have emacs installed on two machines, with both installs using a similar spacemacs config. On both, C-M-i is bound to the command complete-symbol.

I am editing different org files on the machines, and am trying to add internal links to elsewhere in the same document. The way this works on one machine is that if I type [[* then C-M-i I get prompted to enter a pattern which then gives me a filtered list of matching locations in the doc. I can choose one of these and the link is created correctly.

On the other machine, when I hit C-M-i I get a message saying simply [No matches].

What should I check to get the completion working the way I want (as in the first example)?

## Update

It looks like the completion does work on both boxes, it's just on one I was trying to create the link in a headline (which didn't work), whereas on the other box the link was body text, not a headline. It appears that creating links in headlines is a problem, at least in my setup, which is a bit weird as I can create a bunch of links as a nested list and then convert those to headline structure.

Comment: Interesting question: the answer probably lies somewhere deep in `pcomplete.el` but the details are fuzzy to me (to say the least) ATM.